# Sqlite insert and update values of other columns

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two tables; a 'parent' and a 'child' table. (not SQLite defitinions, just something i call them)

Everytime a child-object is created, it is assigned the value 0 in one of its columns.
When a new parent-object is created, every unassigned child-object, has to update the value mentioned before, to the parent-object's ID. My code looks like this:

```
public long createWorkout(String workoutName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, workoutName);

    //Creates a new parent-object (a workout - the childs are exercises)
    //the generated ID is returned as a long (workout_pk_id)
    long workout_pk_id = db.insert(TABLE_WORKOUT, null, values);

    //Selects all objects in the child-table with KEY_WORKOUT_ID = 0 (the column mentioned before)

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " WHERE " + KEY_WORKOUT_ID + " == " + 0;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //Takes each found object with value 0, and updates the value to the returned parent-ID from before.
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String k = "UPDATE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " SET " + KEY_WORKOUT_ID + " == " + workout_pk_id;
            db.execSQL(k);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return workout_pk_id;
}
```

But for some reason this doesn't work. The ID the childs/exercises remains 0. Can you help me?
I don't know if the error is somewhere in the setup of my tables, in that case i could provide some more information.
Thanks in advance. /Jeppe

EDIT: This is used in android, and I have debugged and verified that the workout_pk_id is returned, 45 objects are found in the selectQuery and yet it doesn't work. I also tried ContentValues to update the values, didn't work.

Edited the " == " to " = ", but the value is still not updated.
This is from eclipse - I've created a workout called "test", with the ID 160.
The exercise "test1" has the ID 430 (unique) but the workout_id is still 0.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since I did any Android stuff but I believe the "==" operator is incorrect:

String k = "UPDATE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " SET " + KEY_WORKOUT_ID + " == " + workout_pk_id;

The operator you're using is a comparative operator, "=" is the assignment operator.

I also believe there is a better way to do what you are trying to do, currently refreshing my memory on Android so I'll get back to you. In the meantime tell me if replacing the operator works

Comment: I have updated my post with your reponse, and some new information.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so another way you can do this is by using subqueries. So it would look something like:

`UPDATE TABLE_EXCERCISE SET KEY_WORKOUT_ID = WORKOUT_PK_ID WHERE KEY_WORKOUT_ID = 
(
*subquery here to select parent object ids*
)`

Here's a link to help:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm

Let me know how this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look to your update query.
It has to be:

```java
String k = "UPDATE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " SET " + KEY_WORKOUT_ID + " = " + workout_pk_id;
```

Look at the "=" between KEY_WORKOUT_ID and workout_pk_id.

Comment: I have updated my post with your reponse, and some new information.

Comment: I forgot to say, that your update method need to know which row you want to set.
Do like this:
String k = "UPDATE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " SET " + KEY_WORKOUT_ID + " = " + workout_pk_id + " WHERE "+ PrimaryKey_ID + " == " +  cursor.getString(numberOfCell);

Comment: What do you mean by 'which one'? When i'm using the cursor, doesn't it automatically know that it's the KEY_WORKOUT_ID of the current object that needs to be updated?

Comment: By PrimaryKey_ID, do you then mean the Exercise? and by numberOfCell, you mean the column with these ID's? This doesn't work. :-/

Comment: With primaryKey_id i mean your primaryKey of the current row you are want to update and with numberOfCell i mean the column where you can find the primaryKey of the TABLE_EXERCISE.
Example your TABLE_EXERCISE  is like this:
[data1| data2 | pk_id]
than the code should look like this:
String k = "UPDATE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " SET " + KEY_WORKOUT_ID + " = " + workout_pk_id + " WHERE pk_id = " + cursor.getString(2);

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either. String k = "UPDATE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " SET " + KEY_WORKOUT_ID + " = " + workout_pk_id + " WHERE " + KEY_PK_EXERCISE_ID + " == " + cursor.getString(0); Since KEY_PK_EXERCISE_ID is the first column in TABLE_EXERCISE (with Primary Key)

Comment: Please also change in your condition "==" to "=". The syntax in sqlite is that in a condition you also use "=".

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I'm gonna see if the problem is elsewhere.. Thanks for your suggestions though. :-)